# Change "Cortana voice input" keyboard shortcut back to Windows+C

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, cortana

When Windows 10 launched, I was able to bring up Cortana in "voice input" mode on my PC with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Recently (possibly after the recent Summer 2016 "Anniversary Update"), I now need to hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open Cortana in "voice input" mode.

My question: Is there a way to get Windows to change the shortcut key for Cortana in voice input mode back to just <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (without resorting to a 3rd-party utility like Autohotkey)?

Comment: If the previous shortcut is not connected to Cortana what is it connected to?  If the shorcut was changed what you want won't be possible without a third-party solution.

Comment: @Ramhound: As far as I've been able to determine, the Win+C shortcut isn't being used for anything now.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to re-enable "Hey Cortana" and the Keyboard shortcut will start working again assuming you have no shortcut conflicts.

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-hey-cortana-on-windows-10/

Comment: I do have "Hey Cortana" enabled and working fine, but as described in the question, the Win+C keyboard shortcut isn't working.